# Does loading Firebase Storage image with Glide generate billing expenses?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to know if this action that I am doing in my application generates expenses for Firebase Storage. That is,
if regardless of the times I do the following action it will generate some expense in Firebase billing.

I have images stored in storage, and I upload these images to an ImageView using the Glide library, like this:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse(pictureUser);
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

I have a chat application, and in each message on the adapter I want to upload the user's photo this way, using Glide, so, as there are many uploads, I wanted to know if every time I run this code snippet, it generates some billing expenses of the firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using this in chat activity this means that same image may probably load many of times.
To decrease the number of images that download I suggest you to use instead of:

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

replace it by :

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
      .load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
      .into(imageView);
```

by this way, you are activating the cache mode. this means the Glide will search in the cache if it exists then will upload it from the internet.

I advise you to use Picasso instead of Glide. it works better in mode offline than Glide:

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(url)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            // Try again online if cache failed
                            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                                    .load(url)
                            .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
                                    .into(imageView);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I didn't know about it from the cache, I'll probably switch to your code, thanks, Akram!

Comment: Akram, I decided to continue using Glide. Do you know how I can check if the image was loaded by the cache, by Glide? Just so I can confirm that it is recovering correctly without downloading the images again.

Comment: yes just turn off the internet and you'll notice that the image is still loaded

Comment: But the images always loaded normally with the internet turned off using the code I put in the post, without the .diskCacheStrategy

Comment: the recent version of Glide by default save in the cache by using "DiskCacheStrategy.DATA"

Answer (score 0):

Any time your code download a file, it will be billed as egress from Cloud Storage.

With Glide, it as a disk cache enabled by default, so it should only download a URL once and reuse it from cache (as long as it remains in cache).  That would not be billed, since it's not downloading anything from the cloud.

Comment: This is kind of confusing, I thought that this line of Glide code did not download the image, it just placed the image of the URL on the internet on the imageView. But since this code generates Storage expenses, if a malicious person has the URL of the Storage photo and executes this code several times, in some way that he doesn't leave in the cache, will it still generate costs in my Firebase project?

Comment: How would Glide populate the imageview without downloading the URL?  And yes, a malicious person could incur lots of costs.  That is true for all publicly accessible cloud products.